# Why these two structs have different size in the memory?

Tags: go, struct, compiler-optimization

Suppose I have these two structs:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type A struct {
    int8
    int16
    bool
}

type B struct {
    int8
    bool
    int16
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(A{}), unsafe.Sizeof(B{})) // 6 4
}
```

Size of `A` is 6 bytes. however, the size of `B` is 4 bytes.
I assume that it's related to their layout in the memory, but I'm not sure I understand why it's behave like this.
Isn't something that the compiler can detect and optimize? (rearrange the fields order)

[Link to the code](https://play.golang.org/p/204xci7QlXS)

Comment: That's not an "optimization", it's padding and alignment. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees

Comment: By saying optimization, I'm talking about rearranging the fields order.

Comment: You can't rearrange the fields of a struct, because it's no longer the same struct. A struct implies a certain memory layout.

Comment: "Isn't something that the compiler can detect and optimize? (rearrange the fields order)", I don't think Go compiler can do this at this point, but it something a compiler can do. Rust compiler can do it: https://blog.rust-lang.org/2017/06/08/Rust-1.18.html

Comment: @Akavall, …that is, unless you actually do not want it to rearrange stuff—say, to communicating with non-Go code. Which leads us to the wonderful world of pragmas etc which are unlikely to be implemented in Go, I reckon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Padding due to alignment.

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Size and alignment guarantees](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees)
>
> For the numeric types, the following sizes are guaranteed:
>
> ```
> type                                 size in bytes
>
> byte, uint8, int8                     1
> uint16, int16                         2
> uint32, int32, float32                4
> uint64, int64, float64, complex64     8
> complex128                           16
> ```
>
> The following minimal alignment properties are guaranteed:
>
> - For a variable x of any type: unsafe.Alignof(x) is at least 1.
> - For a variable x of struct type: unsafe.Alignof(x) is the largest of all the values unsafe.Alignof(x.f) for each field f of x, but at least
>     1.
> - For a variable x of array type: unsafe.Alignof(x) is the same as the alignment of a variable of the array's element type.
>
> A struct or array type has size zero if it contains no fields (or
>   elements, respectively) that have a size greater than zero. Two
>   distinct zero-size variables may have the same address in memory.

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type A struct {
    x int8
    y int16
    z bool
}

type B struct {
    x int8
    y bool
    z int16
}

func main() {
    var a A
    fmt.Println("A:")
    fmt.Println("Size:   ", unsafe.Sizeof(a))
    fmt.Printf("Address: %p %p %p\n", &a.x, &a.y, &a.z)
    fmt.Printf("Offset:  %d %d %d\n", unsafe.Offsetof(a.x), unsafe.Offsetof(a.y), unsafe.Offsetof(a.z))
    fmt.Println()
    var b B
    fmt.Println("B:")
    fmt.Println("Size:   ", unsafe.Sizeof(b))
    fmt.Printf("Address: %p %p %p\n", &b.x, &b.y, &b.z)
    fmt.Printf("Offset:  %d %d %d\n", unsafe.Offsetof(b.x), unsafe.Offsetof(b.y), unsafe.Offsetof(b.z))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/_8yDMungDg0

Output:

```
A:
Size:    6
Address: 0x10410020 0x10410022 0x10410024
Offset:  0 2 4

B:
Size:    4
Address: 0x10410040 0x10410041 0x10410042
Offset:  0 1 2
```

---

You may be matching an external `struct`, perhaps in another language. It's up to you to tell the compiler what you want. The compiler doesn't guess.

Comment: Maybe replace the second row of printfs with `fmt.Printf("%d %d %d\n", unsafe.Offsetof(a.x), unsafe.Offsetof(a.y), unsafe.Offsetof(a.z))` ?

Comment: I'd also recommend to the OP to read [this](https://dave.cheney.net/2015/10/09/padding-is-hard).